# Continuously logging in F#

Tags: .net, f#, printf, string-formatting

I'm trying to create 2 logging functions: one is to directly print to stdout, another is to print with an antecedent string `[Error]`.

```
let log message =
    printfn message

let twError (tw:System.IO.TextWriter) message =
    tw.Write("[Error] {0}", message)

let error (message:Printf.StringFormat<_>) =
    let format = Printf.TextWriterFormat<_>(sprintf "[Error] %A" message)
    log format

let date = System.DateTime.Now
log "%A" twError date
error "%s" <| date.ToString()
```

As you can see, in the `error` function I need to make a new string, then convert it to a `TextWriterFormat` type. But this will be less efficient than writing directly to the stream, how should I change the `error` function to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [`Printf.kprintf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/printf.kprintf%5B'result,'t%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) family of functions. Their documentation is *very* hard to understand, but the concept is simple:

- `printf` takes a format string (and arguments), formats it, and then prints it to the console
- `sprintf` takes a format string (and arguments), formats it, and then returns it as a string
- `kprintf` takes a format string (and arguments), formats it, and then passes it (as a string) to a function that you provide. That function should take in a string and do whatever you want with it.

For example:

```
open Printf

let addDateTime (s : string) =
    sprintf "%A: %s" DateTime.UtcNow s

sprintf "%A" [1; 2; 3]  // Returns "[1; 2; 3]"
kprintf addDateTime "%A" [1; 2; 3]  // Returns "2017-05-26 06:05:00: [1; 2; 3]"

let printDateTime (s : string) =
    printfn "%A: %s" DateTime.UtcNow s

printfn "%A" [1; 2; 3]  // Prints "[1; 2; 3]"
kprintf printDateTime "%A" [1; 2; 3]  // Prints "2017-05-26 06:05:00: [1; 2; 3]"
```

So your `error` function could simply become:

```
let errorLogger (s : string) = printfn "[Error] %s" s
let error msg = kprintf errorLogger msg

error "Oops: %A" [1; 2; 3]   // Prints "[Error] Oops: [1; 2; 3]"
```

Experiment with `kprintf` a bit more and see what you can do with it. It's a very powerful function, and it's a shame that more people don't know about it.

Comment: The answer is good, but I also discovered that there are plenty of duplicates or near duplicates, which gives additional information and examples. Search `[f#] kprintf`.

Comment: @BentTranberg When I search with your query, I find that `kprintf` is much slower comparing to `TextWriter`, is there other method that is as fast as `TextWriter`?

Comment: @MiP - Where are you finding that `kprintf` is slower than `TextWriter`? I haven't been able to find the source you're looking at. Also, why do you need it to be speedy? It sounds to me like you may be doing premature optimization.

Comment: @rmunn I found from your anwser `takes a format string, formats it, and then passes it (as a string)`, making new string may seem slower comparing to directly write to a stream.

Comment: @MiP - The cost of making a new string is *trivial*; you're worrying about speed at the wrong stage of the design process. It's time to quote Donald Knuth again: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."

Comment: @MiP - Also, if the cost of copying a single string worries you, then I suggest pondering the fact that in F# (as in other programming languages), just about *everything you do* will involve a data copy. `List.filter`? You just copied the entire contents of the list. `Array.append`? Ditto. Worrying about copying a single string is a textbook example of worrying over trivial inefficiencies. The *largest* inefficiency in any computer program is **you, the programmer**. (That's a generic "you", not you specifically). The most important thing you can do is to minimize *that* inefficiency by ...

Comment: ... organizing your code in such a way that it's **easy to understand** 5-6 months later, when you come back to it after being on another project. Easy to understand code leads to fewer bugs, which leads to FAR less time spent debugging and far more time spent writing new features. And easy-to-understand code is also easier to optimize -- **later**, once your program is complete. You should **never** worry about a single string allocation in the design stages of your program, because that's *almost* always going to be a complete waste of time (you'll probably rewrite that function anyway!)

Comment: "... I find that ..."  Certain parts of F# that were known to be slow, has been optimized considerably, so if you read something about that somewhere, I believe you can ignore it. In addition to what rmunn says, be aware that newer versions of compilers, libraries and hardware can be expected to increase the speed of your software as time passes.